# 'Registered_Courses' object has no attribute 'course_set' Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am really stuck on this error and it does not make sense why it does not follow the relationship backward on Registered_Courses on the foreign key for Courses when i use course_set

views.py

```
def registered_coursesView(request, username):
    '''Page to display the registered courses of a user.'''
    registeredCourses = Registered_Courses.objects.get(owner = request.user) 
    courseInfo = registeredCourses.course_set.all()
    context = {'registeredCourses': registeredCourses, 'courseInfo':courseInfo} 
    return render(request, 'safetyCourseApp/registered_courses.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    '''Offered Course information.'''
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    registered_ppl = models.IntegerField() 

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.name

class Registered_Courses(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a Course."""
    registered_course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return f'{self.owner}'
```

Please let me know what you guys think. I cannot think of a reason why this is not working. Thanks!

Comment: courseInfo = registeredCourses.course_set.all() this you can remove from your views and can call in your templates by for item in object.course_set.all

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified in your **models**, each `Registered_Courses` will have a FK to `Course`, So ***each*** `Course` can have multiple `Registered_Courses`.

But you are trying to get multiple `Course` objects from a single `Registered_Courses`

The backward relationship is something like:

```
>>> course = Course.objects.first()
>>> course.registered_courses_set
```